# Memory leak using queues/lists

Tags: c#, collections, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I am using Queues and lists.

The list object has strings added to it and the Queue object has byte arrays written to it.

On my dev PC which is a quad core there are no memory issues.

On my test pc which is a dual core the app exits because of a memory exception after say about 8 hours of running.

I have been using JetBrains dotMemory analyser to try and pin-point where the memory overloads occurs.

I traced 2 culprits and it it tells me that some bytes (which will increment over time) are not released from the queue and yet the queue count is zero.

The same applies for the list object. It tells me that strings that have been added to the list (and removed) have not been removed from memory.

I am using .Net 4.0 and C#.

I am looking at setting the Capacity and the TrimAccess methods. I have also read that using 4.5 of the Framework will make this problem go away.

Whilst I set my tests up (which will take a few hours to run) I would to pre-empt that this will not give me the solution I need and so I pose my question/dilemma here as well.

Thanks

My code for for the byte queue is like this:

```
Queue<byte[]> byteQueue = new Queue<byte[]>() //module declaration    

//Somewhere in a function:        
byte[] imageInBytes = //convert image to bytes    
byteQueue.Enqueue(imageInBytes);


//Elsewhere in a a function:    
byte[] retreivedBytes = byteQueue.dequeue();    
//post byte array to a WCF service.
```

Comment: It would be easier with some code

Comment: @Lloyd hi, I added the code for the byte queue. I did not originally add the code because I wanted to know if it is a known thing with using queues (etc).  If I was storing objects I could understand but a byte array? But, good point, the more info I can give the better - thanks :)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson You have only posted very brief snippets of code that are not very illustrative, how do you know that the memory leak isn't caused by some other bit of code?  Memory leaks can be very tricky to solve, can you post a valid compilable piece of example code that recreates the problem.

Comment: @ben Hi Ben, that is a fair question. Well, I have previously commented out the other code and just let the bare bones of what you see running. Also, like I stated in my question the JetBrains Memory tool tells me this is where the build up of memory occurs..

Comment: If your images are larger than 85000 bytes, you may have a problem with memory fragmentation. See more here: https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/the-dangers-of-the-large-object-heap/

Comment: @AdrianTrifan Hi, thank you for that link. looking at it now.  But, my typical image size is 17K and the image is properly disposed off after getting the byte array 'version' of it. Thanks for ur thinking :)

Comment: Since you are working with images, the first idea is not to look at the collection as the culprits but at the gdi resources..

Comment: Hi, yes, I have done that and I agree with your thought process.  I could not find any issues and the bytes that are retained in memory as identified in Jet Brains memory tool tells me that these queues are the culprits as it still thinks that there are bytes stored inside my queues even though the count is zero

Comment: a Queue<> doesn't auto reduce its internal capacity just because you dequeue something. i suspect you have to call TrimToSize() to do that. this may be the cause of the memory leak.

Comment: Have you logged out the memory usage profile to see when its increasing memory and how?

Comment: @user3973227 hi, thanks for commenting. I have put that in now and I am running the app. I will know in about 8hrs!  :)

Comment: @Lloyd HI, are you referring to Jet Brains?

Comment: @AndrewSimpson any memory or diagnostics tracing where you can log the memory usage over the lifetime to see if its a steady increase and does calling gc.Collect resolve the issue?

Comment: @Lloyd hi, thanks for commenting again. Well, Jet Brains gives me the option of taking a snapshot when ever I want and I have done so over a period of several hours.  In all cases the memory increase is in these queues. I am debating whether to use GC.Collect or not as this will force the garbage collector will it not?  I am not sure whether this is a good thing and I am still acquiring the skills to determine this :)

Comment: I've had the same issues and found it using Redgate ANTS profiler and recording the profile, you can set events like memory size etc. What about where you convert the image to byte array is there any references there?

Comment: hi, I enclose it in a using statement which is inside a try-catch...